# SharePoint 2013 - Issues staggering out custom Javascript calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

So the company I'm working for is looking for plenty of "OOB" Sharepoint functionality, until they decide they want it made completely custom... In trying to be fluid w/ what they want/their changes, there is a lot more client side rendering than server side.  I know it's hackish, but blame Sharepoint. The main issue I'm currently having is that I need to have a .js page call it's function after Sharepoint does it's rendering of search results.  Then again when the refiner is clicked... or on page refresh.  But, Sharepoint has their own scripts that run and do their thing, and it wipes mine out.  The only working solution I've come up with is setting a timeout on the function, but I hate doing that... The standard JQuery queues aren't doing anything for me either...

Here are some examples I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    checkForHash();
});

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("finalPageLoad");

$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
    clearDefaultJS();
    postProcessing();
});

function postProcessing() {
    var completedPull = 0;
    setTimeout(setUpPage, 1000);
    if (completedPull == 0) {
        setTimeout(setUpPage, 2000);
    }
}

function finalPageLoad() {
    postProcessing();
}

function setUpPage() {
    clearDefaultJS();
    bioDocumentPull();
    collapseFilters();
}
```

I know these may not be the most useful snippets, but company security and other reasons keep me from posting the rest.  Any help in proper ways to call functions after everything is completed (AJAX calls, other script calls, post backs, partial post backs, section reloads) would be of immense help to me, and hopefully other SharePoint beginners.

Comment: Sometimes I use `setTimeout()`, or I try to find the function in the Microsoft JS files and I overwrite it with my own code... But as you can see, nothing very clean :-(

Comment: You can try to use SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(func, depScriptFileName); http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff411788(v=office.14).aspx
function. But you need to know which script provide as second parameter.